# Rig moving to another location in edit mode

Tags: rigging, edit-mode, origin

I was rigging a character. After my rigging was finished I got out of edit mode and the rig moved away from the character. If I move the rig and align with the character in object or pose mode. The rig move in edit mode. Even if I reset the origin it does not work. My enter code here question might not be clear just open my file and answer my question.
Here is the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_WGivtF_Y7PThvR8xbzmY_8rPUjVRePH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you try to delete all keyframes? i didn't see a problem after that

Answer (score 1):

You've moved your armature in *Pose* mode, so it is not aligned with the *Rest* pose anymore. The *Rest* pose will show the bones as they are in *Edit* mode. To reset the bones position, select them all in *Pose* mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (reset location), <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (reset rotation) and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (reset scale).

Comment: Thanks it worked. After reseting things in the rig another problem came up. I was not able to select any object. Then I restarted blender and everything was fine.